# Is this a good site for learning to play chess?

Tags: learning

Is this a good website for a mature adult who picks up new topics quickly to self-teach chess?

Comment: It's a good site to know about, but you probably won't use it regularly for your own questions until you are much farther along. For now, you should simply look over a [series of past posts](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions) to get a feeling for how others use this site. Past questions can also lead you to insights that might be valuable in learning faster.

Comment: chesscademy.com

Answer (score 11):

**No, it's not,** but it might still be very beneficial to you. (Chess) Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, so:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

(taken from [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

So *don't* expect any tutorials here, or the possibility to play an actual game against someone. However, browsing through the site you will find a lot of resources which might help you - [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/what-book-should-i-refer-to-to-begin-learning-chess?rq=1) for example. If you need a resource on a specific topic, and nobody has asked it before, please go ahead and ask for it.